# Adding 1 one on to an integer each time?

Tags: java

```
public class LockPicker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println ("Picking the lock...");
        boolean lock = false;
        while (lock==false)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            int number = (int)(Math.random() * 99 + 1);
            System.out.println(number);
            if (number!=55){
                lock = false;
                ++counter;
            }else{
                lock = true;
                System.out.println("That took "+counter+" tries!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hello,

I have been set a task where I have to write a program that will generate random numbers between 10 and 99. The program
should continue to repeat until the number 55 is created. The program should output how
many attempts it made to get 55.

It works fine, and stops when it reaches 55. However, the counter always remains at 0. It never adds 1 onto the variable counter.

Comment: `int counter = 0;` on top of the while loop.

Comment: An important lesson here is that of the *scope of the variable*. [See here](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) for a simplified explanation - maybe it will help your understanding.

Comment: Your code can be simplified a lot. You do not need `boolean lock` at all. You can use something called `break`. There is no need for an `else` clause either. You can have `++counter;` at the end of the loop and right before that have `if (number == 55) { System.out.println("That took " + counter + " tries!"); break; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the `int counter = 0;` line before the `while` loop.

Everytime the loop runs, you are initializing the `counter` variable to 0, that is why it always remains 0.

Comment: @JoeMaynard you can accept the answer by clicking the big check mark besides the answer if it helped you.